# Почему не работает библиотека pytube: "'YouTube' object has no attribute 'get'"

Tags: python, pytube

Не работает код, программа должна скачать видео

```
from pytube import YouTube

video_link = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZpVwAeLzm4'

yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90KZnwrVMgY")
video = yt.get('mp4', '720p')
video.download('/download/')
```

`pip install pytube3` делал

Comment: Не вижу у класса YouTube метода `get`: https://github.com/nficano/pytube/blob/8c598376bb2432a5ff25ef2cd0ed1080236d5d62/pytube/__main__.py#L31

Comment: Я тоже, а он есть. Точнее есть ошибка, я делаю все строго по примерам из интернета

Comment: Те примеры врут. А скиньте ссылку на пример, любопытно. А так, думаю вам понадобится пример https://github.com/nficano/pytube#quick-start . Используйте `.streams.filter` укажите там `file_extension` и `resolution`, думаю поможет

Comment: @gil9red http://san-tit.blogspot.com/2017/02/youtube.html
[Ссылка]
Как скачать видео из YouTube с помощью Python
http://san-tit.blogspot.com/2017/02/youtube.html

Comment: @gil9red и так не только в этом примере, а везде

Comment: Когда-то `get` был в нем: https://github.com/nficano/pytube/blob/442786af48a411006a2c302410a6c2abce8ac82b/pytube/api.py#L221 но уже c октября 2017 того метода там нет: https://github.com/nficano/pytube/commit/6960bc12923f6c2600c5adef816856d8df4de983#diff-c9becc76762df8093797c1bd95d998d6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда-то метод `get` был в нем: https://github.com/nficano/pytube/blob/442786af48a411006a2c302410a6c2abce8ac82b/pytube/api.py#L221 но уже [c октября 2017 того метода там нет](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/commit/6960bc12923f6c2600c5adef816856d8df4de983#diff-c9becc76762df8093797c1bd95d998d6), поэтому нужно использовать другие методы.

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f87a0266c2ae7920e2be6215fb3fd306ba2b5d09/pytube__examples/main.py)

```
from pytube import YouTube

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90KZnwrVMgY'

yt = YouTube(url)
print(f'Download video {yt.title!r}: {url}')

streams = yt.streams\
    .filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4', resolution='720p')\
    .order_by('resolution')

video = streams[-1]
print('Stream url:', video.url)
video.download()
```

**PS.**

Хотел бы отметить, что:

- Нужно именно `pip install pytube3 --upgrade`, а не `pip install pytube3`, иначе будет ошибка при импорте: `ImportError: cannot import name 'quote' from 'pytube.compat'`
- Нужно указывать атрибут `progressive=True`, чтобы получить поток с видео и аудио в одном файле
- Лучше проверять `streams`, т.к. он может быть пустым, если по фильтру не нашлось потоков ([см. в примере](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/f87a0266c2ae7920e2be6215fb3fd306ba2b5d09/pytube__examples/main.py#L23))